# Why is the size of the app in the AppStore half the size of the build in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

Developing an application, release branch, when published in the App Store weighs 100MB after installation. The same branch if you build it locally from Xcode weighs 200MB. Sometimes a similar result is observed in TestFlight. Question, are there any specifics of building an application in the App Store, which results in a difference of half the weight?

I am a tester, and I do not understand the details, but it is important to solve the problem, please advise me in what direction to look for a solution.

Googled and talked to the developer. I need a hint in which direction to think.

Comment: During development. a lot of debug information is stored. This is a significant amount of the difference...

Comment: This may help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing-your-app-s-size

Comment: "it is important to solve the problem" while the size is _smaller_ than what you expected -- so what is the problem? what are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 reasons:

1. Debug builds contains more information than release builds.
2. In release mode, usually we upload universal IPA to the appstore. Which will include data for all variants (Different iPhones, iPad, mac). You will only download thinned version of the app which will be less in space.

Read more at: [Reducing your app’s size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing-your-app-s-size)